# PDO 2300 upon insert though no rows exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$compost = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` 
(`PRIMARY`, `some`, `content`, `rows`, `and`, `boolean`) 
VALUES ('', :binded, :param, :inputs, :blah, 0)") ;
```

the primary key iterates automatically and clasicaly this means my inserts do not need to give actual input for that column just ' ' is fine.

However this keeps throwing a 2300 error.

no rows are indexes or keys just the primary and a dumped all the table rows before attempting this script.

So I removed the primary

```
$compost = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` 
( `some`, `content`, `rows`, `and`, `boolean`) 
VALUES ( :binded, :param, :inputs, :blah, 0)") ;
```

but it still throws the error, going to make a new table and try that

Comment: Please always post the full error output you receive.

Answer (score 3):

Leave the primary key if it is auto increment.

```
$compost = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` 
(`some`, `content`, `rows`, `and`, `boolean`) 
VALUES (:binded, :param, :inputs, :blah, 0)") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `PRIMARY` column name is 'PRIMARY' you can try:

```
$compost = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` 
(`PRIMARY`, `some`, `content`, `rows`, `and`, `boolean`) 
VALUES (PRIMARY, :binded, :param, :inputs, :blah, 0)") ;
```

or just not to mention that field at all:

```
$compost = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` 
(`some`, `content`, `rows`, `and`, `boolean`) 
VALUES (:binded, :param, :inputs, :blah, 0)") ;
```